# Dbeaver : connection is closed by foreign host

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, pg-hba.conf, postgresql.conf

im working on vmware on ubuntu

i want connect util in postgres...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PHuc.png)

im also change pg_hba.conf and postgres.conf

im changed listen addresses ='*'
and

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5dgq.png)

Comment: The problem seems to be with your SSH tunnel.  If you don't want to use an SSH tunnel, then you need to go to the SSH tab and uncheck the box.

Comment: oh thanks to comment ... you mean checking the ssh option in vmware,, right?

Comment: No, in the dbeaver dialog box from your first image, there is an 'SSH' tab.  I think that there is where the problem is.

Comment: oh thank u... i will do that after work :)

Comment: thanks a lot ,, im had it uncheck SSH box.,.., finally connect